# What does this linux kernel panic message: sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename mean?

Tags: embedded, kernel-panic, sysfs

```
   [1.503917] NET: Registered protocol family 17
    [    1.504612] libphy: mdiobus_find: mii bus [igb_enet_mii_bus] found
        1.504711] sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/kernel/marvell/access'
        [    1.504726] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.19.101 #0
        [    1.504731] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
        [    1.504735] Backtrace: 
        [    1.504744] Function entered at [<80013a28>] from [<80013d60>]
        [    1.504757]  r7:00000000 r6:60000013 r5:00000000 r4:806437b4
        [    1.504762] Function entered at [<80013d48>] from [<804e9eb4>]
        [    1.504766] Function entered at [<804e9e1c>] from [<8013fffc>]
        [    1.504776]  r7:00000000 r6:80576d94 r5:e9379000 r4:eef4b000
        [    1.504781] Function entered at [<8013ff9c>] from [<8013fcbc>]
        [    1.504790]  r7:00000000 r6:e9379000 r5:ffffffef r4:8063860c
        [    1.504796] Function entered at [<8013fb50>] from [<8013fd68>]
        [    1.504803]  r6:e9387740 r5:8063860c r4:00000000
```

While this is the specific kernel panic/trace I see booting kernel v4.19.101 and NOT with kernel v4.1.16, what does this error mean in general? Information from Google is sort of all over the place.

Answer (score 3):

The message means that [a `sysfs` path was registered twice](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.4/source/fs/sysfs/dir.c#L29) for some reason; either from a driver registering it twice, or from two drivers trying to register the same name.

Comment: How can it be fixed?

Comment: Are you using the mainline kernel, or a distribution kernel, or perhaps a Freescale image?

Comment: mainline, debian 10 buster